# NotifyDataSetChanged not work

Tags: android

I met an issue, very weird.

I clear a data source of adapter, then call NotifyDatasetChanged(), the empty view is showed. But, when I use a runnable to repopulate the data source, then call NotifydatasetChanged(), the UI is not changed, when I click the screen, the data will be shown.

```
private void func(){
    clearData();

    adapter.NotifyDatasetChanged();

    call runnable();
}
runnable(){
    repopulateData();

    sendMessageToHandler();
}
mHandler(){
    adapter.NotifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't working, you have to call it in the UI thread.

This is why your data added or modified by Thread.

So, you have to call notifyDataSetChanged() in the UI thread.

Below code can help you.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks man! I have found this is an issue in android 4.x, but it has been fixed.https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68563&can=1&q=NotifyDataSetChanged&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars